# $\log \Gamma(z + 1) = \log \Gamma (z) + \log z$ issue

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, special-functions, gamma-function

I was reading proof of Binet's first expression for $\log \Gamma(z)$; that is for $\Re z > 0$,
$$
\log \Gamma(z) = \left(z - \frac 1 2\right)\log z - z + \frac 1 2 \log (2\pi) + \int_0^\infty \left(\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 t + \frac 1 {e^t - 1} \frac {e^{-tz}}t \right) \operatorname{d}\!t.
$$

One of the steps was using the following: for $\Re z > 0$,
$$\log\Gamma(z+1) = \log z + \log \Gamma(z). \qquad\qquad(*)$$
At first glance it seems obvious, since $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$. But equality $\log(uv) = \log u + \log v$ holds only up to difference of $2\pi i$ in general. Here $\log$ is taken to be discontinuous at non positive real numbers.

If $\Re \Gamma(z) > 0$, then there is no additional $\pm 2\pi i$, but this
inequality is not always true in our domain.

I was told that Weierstrass form could be helpful, but I don't see how.
How to show $(*)$?

Comment: I believe the Wolfram MathWorld article [Log Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html) provides insight. Note $\text{log$\Gamma$}(z)$ is not the same thing as $\log(\Gamma(z))$. While its not always true that $\log(\Gamma(z+1))=\log(z)+\log(\Gamma(z))$ for $\Re(z)>0$, it is always true that $\text{log$\Gamma$}(z+1)=\log(z)+\text{log$\Gamma$}(z)$ for $\Re(z)>0$.

Comment: the easy proof is to note that all the functions in $\log\Gamma(z+1) = \log z + \log \Gamma(z)$ are analytic functions on $\Re z >0$ so (by the identity theorem) it is enough to prove the result for $z=r>0$ where it is fairly obvious at least if you show that for $r>0$ where $\Gamma(r)>0$ the function $\log \Gamma$ is identical to the usual real value of $\log (\Gamma(r))$